# How to set content to easyui panel with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I have a problem in using easyui panel, so I am here needing somebody's help , even thought i find a few people use easyui in stackoverflow.

I have a panel in my page like:

```
<div  class="easyui-panel" title="" id="pp"  closed="true" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

And then, I want to put a value of a input value to this pp panel.

The input value and button code is :

```
<input type="text" style="width:97%;height:40px" id="drafterId" value='ths'>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="drafter()" data-options="plain:true,iconCls:'icon-man'">bt</a>
```

Now I want to use drafter function when clicking linkbutton  to realize it :

```
function drafter()
{
    var drf=$("#drafterId").val();
    alert(drf);//works OK
    var drfN="<tr>"+drf+"</tr>";

    $('#pp').panel('refresh', 'drf');   //works fail
}
```

But unlucky, $('#pp').panel('refresh', 'drf');works fail. I have tried another way:

```
$('#pp').html(drf);
```

and

```
$('#pp').innerHTML(drf);
```

They both failed. Who can help me?

Comment: When you say the line fails, does the content get set to ‘drf’ ?

Comment: @corse32, the content got set to 'drf' successfully. I have tried:drf.appendTo($('#pp')), but it fail again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#pp').append(drf);` works OK

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the variable name ‘drf’.

So `$('#pp').panel('refresh', 'drf');`

Becomes`$('#pp').panel('refresh', drf);`

Comment: But when you set the content to a string (‘drf’) it works?